# How to remove a item inside a dictionary value use pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want remove a item inside a dictionary value but i don't know how i many ways but I couldn't

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63a7cd40c93763cb93fb27b4"
  },
  "-1001166788687": {
    "84653426": "<a href=tg://user?id=84653426>Returning</a>"
  },
  "group_name": "T"
}
```

I want remove this

```
"84653426": "<a href=tg://user?id=84653426>Returning</a>"
```

Comment: What would the document look like after your desired update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `$unset` operator:

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": "1"
},
{
  "$unset": {
    "-1001166788687.84653426": 1
  }
})
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zXhWbSq_c01)

Comment: You are welcome! Consider also accepting and upvoting my answer, so other people that have the same issue would know it worked for you.